# What determines if a particular DAC is "good" for audio?

Tags: audio, dac

I want to generate low-end audio (sinewave, sampling rate 8kHz). How to determine if a particular DAC is okay for such application? Is it only the settling time (of course apart from resolution, interface, voltage etc.)?

For example the [AD5601](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5601_5611_5621.pdf) has a maximum settling time of 10µs. At a rate of 8kHz a sample takes 125µs, so I would guess that this particular DAC could handle the sample rate. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AD5601 allows data bits being sent at 30 MHz, each packet takes 16 bits.

\$\frac{30 MHz}{16}=1.875MHz\$.

That means that you can theoretically make waveforms up to the Nyquist frequency which is \$\frac{1.875 MHz}{2} = 937.5 kHz\$.

\$937.5 Khz > 8kHz\$

The slew rate is 5 V/µs, that means that if you got a signal bouncing between 0 and 5 volt, a sine wave of 1Hz of amplitude 2.5 V has a maximum dv/dt at sin(0) => dv/dt = 1*2.5V => 2.5V, so a 2Hz sine wave got a dv/dt of 5V at t = 0. 
5V/µs => X/s = 5*10^6/s, so 2Hz*10^6 => the slew rate supports a whopping 2 Mhz sine wave.

**So yes, you are correct. That DAC is good enough for making sine waves sampled at 8kHz.** What you said, 125 µs and 10 µs, together with the data speed & slew rate => why I said you were correct.

But let's reverse the formula, say you want to output what you sampled.

\$8 kHz × 2 = 16 kHz\$

\$16 kHz × 16 = 256 kHz\$

This means that you need to send one bit every \$\frac{1}{256 kHz} = 3.9 µs\$.

Comment: To put it in more precisely: You can make square waves of arbitrary height at 937.5kHz. If you want a sawtooth with only one intermediate step, you are down at 470kHz, a triangle with only one intermediate step can be output at 235kHz and so on. The frequency goes down very quickly with accuracy.